# How to stop zsh from expanding * (asterisk) in command line?

Tags: zsh

I recently switched to `zsh`. When I was using `bash`, I used to use `echo 2*3 |bc` as a powerful and convenient calculator but in `zsh` the first part of the command result in error message:

```
$ echo 2*3
zsh: no matches found: 2*3
```

I know I can avoid the expansion by adding quote to the string `2*3` but is it possible to bring this feature from `bash` (not expanding asterisk in command argument)?

UPDATE:

In the meaning while I found `bc <<< 2*3` won't trigger the expansion, weird :-(

Comment: The documentation for here strings in `zsh` states that `word` in `<<< word` does not undergo shell expansion, which explains why you don't need to quote `*`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
noglob echo 2*3 | bc
```

And then create an alias around this:

```
calc()
{
   echo $* | bc
}
alias calc='noglob calc'
```

Comment: FWIW, you can do arithmetic evaluation in Zsh using `$(( ))`, you could avoid `bc` by using `calc() { echo $(( $* )) }`